# Como fazer o efeito de fundo dinâmico do iCloud?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Como é que eu consigo fazer o efeito do ecrã de *login* com o fundo como o do [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/) quando se altera o tamanho do *browser*?

Se repararem os objetos ofuscados mudam de posição consoante o tamanho do browser. Na primeira imagem são 2 linhas de objetos por 7 colunas, na segunda imagem são 3 linhas por 5 colunas.

Dá para fazer isso com bootstrap?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navegando na web encontrei uma possível solução para aparência do blur, se necessário, ao que dá para entender é tudo feito por CSS, apenas um JS para acionar o efeito quando necessário, não há muito segredo.

```
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Segue link com instruções do efeito:
http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/6G6jR/1/

Em questão do recolocação dos objetos, os objetos se recolocam sozinhos, um efeito parecido é o [grid-system/thumbnails do bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails).

Comment: Rodrigo alterei a sua resposta para que não fique baseada apenas em links, se não gostar pode sempre reverter. Mas é isso mesmo consegui fazer o que queria com a sua ideia. Obrigado.

Comment: Rodrigo não funciona em internet explore. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Qual versão do IE está sendo utilizada?

Comment: estou a testar com 8,9,10 e 11.

Comment: O efeito blur funciona apenas com o CSS3, ou seja, a partir do IE 11.

Comment: Pois, não sei como resolver o problema... Para já fica sem o efeito, mas deveria arranjar outra forma.

Comment: Desculpe o equivoco, mas me enganei nas informações passadas... na verdade ele funciona a partir do Edge, o IE tem suporte ao filter, mas não ao filter: blur.

Para resolver teria que desenvolver um JS, porém infelizmente não garanto a resposta pois não é exatamente de minha área, me desculpe.

Comment: Obrigado na mesma amigo ;)