# Como posso fazer o efeito blur no IE?

Tags: css, css3, internet-explorer, filter

Estou a usar esse código css para fazer o efeito `blur` numa `div`:

```
.blur
{
    -webkit-filter: blur(25px);
    -moz-filter:    blur(25px);
    -o-filter:      blur(25px);
    -ms-filter:     blur(25px);
    filter:         blur(25px);
}

<div class="blur">
    <!-- HTML code -->
</div>
```

O problema é que os [browsers IExplorer não suportam](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) *filter effects*.

Como posso fazer esse efeito no IE? Há alguma alternativa?

Comment: Relacionada: [Como fazer o efeito de fundo dinâmico do iCloud?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/136352/7210)

Answer (score 1):

*Como vc deu poucos detalhes vou responder com uma opção simples. Pode ser que essa opção não funcione para todos os casos, mas não deixa de ser uma alternativa já que não temos demais detalhes.*

**Opção 1:** Usando `box-shadow`. repare que essa é uma propriedade já muito bem aceita pelos browsers, mesmo os mais antigos! **Elá funciona do I9+** https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

**Opção 2:** Usando `SVG`. Veja que o SVG é bem aceito mesmo pelo IE a partir de versão 9 como vc pode conferir aqui https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

**imagem feita no IE11**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código referente a imagem acima.

A opção com `box-shadow` foi feita nada mais é que um elemento com vários `box-shadows` sobrepostos. Em IEs mais antigos caso ele não aceite mais de um `box-shadow` vc pode sobrepor o elemento inteiro um sobre o outro com `position:absolute`

O SVG basta utilizar o `Filter` `<feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />`. Vc pode fazer como no primeiro exemplo com o filter só no rect ou então no `rect` e no `text` dando a impressão que tudo está com `blur`

```css
body {
    margin: 10px 0 0 40px;
    display: flex;
}
.box {
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.box.bs {
    box-shadow: 
    0px 0px 8px 0px red, 
    0px 0px 8px 0px red, 
    0px 0px 8px 0px red, 
    0px 0px 8px 0px red
}

div {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>DIV com box-shadow</p>
    <div class="box bs" >123</div>
</div>

<div>
    <p>DIV com filtro</p>
    <div class="box" style="filter:blur(2px); width:120px; height: 120px">123</div>
</div>

<div>
    <p>SVG com defs filter</p>
    <svg height="140" width="140">
        <defs>
            <filter id="f1" >
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="120" height="120"  fill="red" filter="url(#f1)" /> 
        <text x="10" y="25" fill="black">123</text>
    </svg>
</div>
<div>
    <p>SVG com defs filter em tudo</p>
    <svg height="140" width="140">
        <defs>
            <filter id="f1" >
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="120" height="120"  fill="red" filter="url(#f1)" /> 
        <text filter="url(#f1)" x="10" y="25" fill="black">123</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Que detalhes necessitas de saber?

Comment: @JorgeB. no caso seria se vc queria aplicar o Blur apenas no background por exemplo, ou em um conjunto de elemento, tipo uma div e tudo que está dentro dela. De qq forma tentei dar exemplos que atendessem as duas situações. Mesmo com mais de 2 anos de atraso na resposta espero que ainda possa ajudar alguém :)

Comment: Pode-me ajudar a mim, que eu ainda tenho sem esse efeito quando é para iE. Quando tiver um tempinho eu vou testar isso.

Comment: @JorgeB. legal, testa ai e veja se funciona! No teste que fiz no IE 11 ficou bom! Qual quer dúvida é só me dar um toque que te ajudo.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

já tentou utilizar filter:progid?

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=25);
```

Caso queira saber mais: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms532979(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Não funciona, porque não é o efeito para uma imagem, é para uma `div` HTML.